# Does Gang Up benefit my Allies?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The feat [Gang Up](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/gang-up-combat) states

> You are considered to be flanking an opponent if at least two of your allies are threatening that opponent

Does this mean my allies are also considered flanking, or only the character (or characters) with `Gang Up`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the RAW are pretty clear: *You* are considered to be flanking. Also, You are *considered* to be flanking, not you *are* flanking.

I'd go with "Only you".

Comment: Correct, only you, unless they have the feat or you have the Inquisitor ability to let your allies benefit from your tactical feats (the only case in which they are worth taking a feat, IMO).